# How to embed taboola in Google AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to embed this Taboola code in my AMP pages

```
<amp-embed width=100 height=100
    type=taboola
    layout=responsive
    heights="(min-width:780px) 64%, (min-width:480px) 98%, (min-width:460px) 167%, 196%"
    data-publisher="amp-demo"
    data-mode="thumbnails-a"
    data-placement="Responsive example - AMP"
    data-article="auto">
</amp-embed>
```

but I get this error:

```
FPO - setup failed: Blocked a frame with origin "https://d-1038632027198192238.ampproject.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Maybe Chrome is preventing a potential cross script security issue? Any way to fix it?

Comment: Hi Andrew! Did you find the solution? I was having the exact same error with Taboola. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Direct Javascript calls between frames and/or windows are only allowed if they conform to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin). If your window and iframe share a common parent domain you can set `document.domain` to "domain lower") one or both such that they can communicate. Otherwise you'll need to look into something like the [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Since content scripts run in the context of a web page and not the extension, they often need some way of communicating with the rest of the extension.

Here's a related SO ticket which discuss about same origin policy: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: yeah I know the theory for iframes but this is different, I am using <amp-embed>, it doesn't look like it is rendered as an iframe so I am looking for a specific workaround